# Only first json item changes onclick, how can I let it work for all items?

Tags: javascript, json, onclick

I'm new to javascript and I can't use jQuery or html in my assignment...
I want to turn various items in my jason green onclick. It works only for the first item in the list, but when I switch around id's so it should be applied to the second item, it doesn't work.

```
for(var i = 0; i < content.length; i++){
  var contentText = content[i];

  var textCH1_2 = document.createElement("p");
  textCH1_2.id = "peterEntersRoom";
  if(content[i].id === "peterEntersRoom"){
    textCH1_2.innerText = contentText.text;
  }
  textContainer1.append(textCH1_2);
}

document.getElementById("peterEntersRoom").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("peterEntersRoom").style.color = "green";
}
```

and the json has this structure:

```
{
    "chapter": 1,
    "id": "peterEntersRoom",
    "character": {
      "main_character": "Mrs. Darling",
      "supporting_character" : [
        "Wendy"
      ],
    },
    "dialogue" : false,
    "text": "Of course"
  },
```

Could someone please help me?

Comment: content is the json object right?

Comment: @NO_GUI yes! the id "peterEntersRoom" will display the text "Of course". That works, but the colour changing for the following items doesn't work. They all have the same json structure, but different text content, They all display, but only the first reacts to onclick

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

And look at my comments within

```
    function bind(content){
            for(var i = 0; i < content.length; i++){
        var contentText = content[i];

        var textCH1_2 = document.createElement("p");
        textCH1_2.id = contentText.id;
        //if(content[i].id === "peterEntersRoom"){
            textCH1_2.innerText = contentText.text;
        //}
        textContainer1.append(textCH1_2);
        // Moved the eventhandler inside the for loop to associate with each text node
        textCH1_2.onclick = function() {
            this.style.color = "green";
        }
    }

   // document.getElementById("peterEntersRoom").onclick = function() {
   //   document.getElementById("peterEntersRoom").style.color = "green";
   // }
}
```

Assuming the content.json looks like this:

```
[
{
"chapter": 1,
"id": "peterEntersRoom",
"character": {
  "main_character": "Mrs. Darling",
  "supporting_character" : [
    "Wendy"
  ]
},
"dialogue" : false,
"text": "Of course"
},
{
"chapter": 2,
"id": "HanaaLeavesRoom",
"character": {
  "main_character": "Mrs. Hope",
  "supporting_character" : [
    "Mark"
  ]
},
"dialogue" : false,
"text": "Good bye!"
}
]
```